# SQL QUERY ERROR "DEFAULT NULL"

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write an sql query in PHP My admin ,but facing an error could any one help please!

**QUERY**

```
ALTER TABLE `transactions` ADD `giftAmount` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `recievingCurrency` ,
ADD `giftCurrency` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `giftAmount`
```

**ERROR**

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `giftAmount`' at line 2**

HELP

Comment: Is the MySQL manual really that hard to understand?

Comment: A nullable column by definition has a default value of `NULL`. The error message is quite clear and point to the exact location of the error. Remove `DEFAULT NULL` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give size of `varchar` datatype like

```
ADD `giftCurrency` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `giftAmount`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not correct. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  ADD `giftAmount`   FLOAT   NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `recievingCurrency` ,
  ADD `giftCurrency` VARCHAR                       AFTER `giftAmount`
```

You don't need to explicitly say `DEFAULT NULL` - it already is NULL by default.